# What Digital Signature Scheme should we use?

Tags: signature, schnorr-signature, voting

My team wants to implement the [ElectionGuard](https://blogs.microsoft.com/on-the-issues/2019/09/24/electionguard-available-today-to-enable-secure-verifiable-voting/) as the main part of an e-voting scheme (even if it is known that e-voting protocols are malleable; for the purposes of the voting scheme it is enough). Note that ElectionGuard security is based on the discrete logarithm problem.

We want to use a Digital Signature Scheme in order to apply a re-voting protocol (to avoid coercion). So we are wondering which one to use. We have been thinking about [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) (for simplicity).

Is a Schnor signature a good option?

---

Another question is about how to properly implement a re-voting system in the e-voting protocol.

In the context of re-voting, you end up with a ballot $b$ which contains the encryption of the votes and some zero knowledge proofs that the ballot is well formed. The idea is to generate a pair signing key/verification key $(sk,vk)$ using the generator of the Schnorr signature scheme, sign the ballot $\sigma = Sign(sk,b)$ and then introduce a number $num$ which will indicate the number of times that this $sk$ has been used (and which be associated uniquely with a particular voter). So the result will be a tuple $(b,\sigma,num)$.

Is this a good procedure? It is secure? At which level?

.

Comment: Often it is better to first ask the first  question and then followup with the second one. As the questions are related, I'll let it stand as the second section is probably the most interesting part of the question. I don't see why any signature scheme could not be dropped in, to be honest. Of course, given that the entire framework relies on the DL problem, using Schnorr or DSA seems to make sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yup, that is what I thought. We want to be as simple as possible (even if its not post-quantum secure).